# Different looks on scrollbars when using USB mouse vs wireless/trackpad in OS X

Tags: css, macos, scrollbar

I just realized that Mac OS X shows different scrollbars in the browsers when a USB mouse is connected or not. I tried the code below and it looks ok, but now when I disconnect the mouse it applies to the wireless settings as well, which I was happy with already (scrollbars only showing when scrolling or hovering it).

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 15px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Can I:
1. Write CSS for the USB mouse only?
2. Do something that makes the USB mouse look/act like the wireless mouse.

Thank you!

Comment: Also, when you connect a trackpad the scrollbars disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I found:
[OSX: Remove scrollbars that appear when using a mouse](https://muffinresearch.co.uk/osx-remove-scrollbars-that-appear-when-using-a-mouse/)

> Fortunately the solution lay in the General preferences pane. All that's needed is to change "Show scroll bars" to "When scrolling" instead of "Automatically based on mouse or trackpad.

[image]

**Conclusion**: I think the solution is beyond our/developers' control. Just leave it to the user.